# python - large and small dataset comparison

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, optimization

I have 2 pandas dataframes in python. One is very small `df1` (<200 rows) and other one is very large `df2` (>20M rows). I want to compare the small df with the large one and **get all the indexes of larger dataframe `df2` for all matching rows.**

I have coded the following -

`df3 = df2[df2['Row Idx'].isin(df1['Row Idx'])]`

In this all the rows of `df2` are compared with `df1` which is not efficient and the execution is very slow. For 200 rows it takes nearly 30 secs. I have tried to run it in Google Colab and AWS also but the performance is similar.

This comparison is done in a loop for ~400K times as per some condition.

Is there way to improve the performance?

Answer (score 0):

a more efficient way would be to do a join between the dataframes - something like:

df1.merge(df2, on='Row Idx)

see more details here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html

also, pandas has performance issues, especially with large datasets, it might be useful to consider some alternatives like:

- [modin](https://modin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) - faster then pandas, works with the same API so transitioning is simpler
- [vaex](https://vaex.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) - also works with memory mapped files (not all data is read into memory) which is very significant - but the API is different, so there's a larger learning curve
- [pyspark](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/index.html)
- [dask](https://dask.org/)